# How to use Ansible with Vagrant locally?

Tags: vagrant, ansible, vagrantfile, vagrant-provision

I followed the official tutorial from: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/guide_vagrant.html

My `Vagrantfile` looks like:

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = '2'

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
  config.vm.box = 'bento/centos-7.2'

  # SSH default root user
  config.ssh.username = 'root'
  config.ssh.password = 'vagrant'

  # Networking
  # config.vm.network :private_network, ip: '192.168.33.16'

  # Provisioning
  config.vm.provision :ansible do |ansible|
    ansible.playbook = 'playbooks/main.yml'
  end
end
```

And my `test.sh` script:

```
ansible-playbook \
  --private-key=.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key \
  -u vagrant \
  -i .vagrant/provisioners/ansible/inventory/vagrant_ansible_inventory \
  playbooks/main.yml \
  $@
```

But when I run the script, I receive the following error:

```
fatal: [default]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.", "unreachable": true}
  to retry, use: --limit @playbooks/main.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
default                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

How to test `ansible-playbook` with `Vagrant`?

Comment: You can use `-i "localhost,"` to run a playbook against the localhost. But are you sure that's what you want here? Don't you want to run against the VM you've created?

Comment: Perhaps I'm reading too much into the title of your question.

Comment: I created Vagrant machine and I want to run a particular playbook agains it.

Comment: Okay. Any reason to run it from a script instead of letting Vagrant run it against the host? That's the way your Vagrantfile is set up.

Comment: I tried your Vagrantfile by running `vagrant up`, and its only complaint is that ansible is not installed on centos, which means that at least it's connecting, even if it won't be able to run ansible there.

Comment: The reason is I want to run a particular tag, not an entire playbook.

Comment: why do you want to connect with `root` ? you should leave the default `vagrant` user, it will sudo any command needed to provision correctly as root

Comment: check that ssh port in `vagrant_ansible_inventory` is the same as actual port mapped to sshd.

Comment: I'm back home and in front of a real dev machine now. ;) I tried your Vagrantfile and your test.sh, and it works fine for me. I'm running Vagrant 1.8.1 and Ansible 2.1.1.0. What versions are you running? Also, can you share your main.yml? Or create a simple main.yml, try that, and share it?

Comment: Please add `-vvv` to the `ansible-playbook` call. Then execute the actual SSH command as shown in the output. That should give a clue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run ansible against host then Vagrant already has [ansible_local](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/ansible_local.html) provisioner.

To run this you have to first install `ansible` on guest machine if it's not already installed. And this can be done from Vagrantfile shell provisioner with `easy_install` or `pip`.